# How to translate a word when user selects a word in website?

Tags: javascript, translation

whenever user selects a word, i want to show a popup that contains translation, suggestions, keywords etc. How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: @Gangaraju Please don't add tags to questions just because you think they might be related. (For instance, [tag:angular-translate] is an internationalization library; it does not translate text for the user.)

Comment: Thank, my english is awful, my question is edit by edit suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/#resources)

The [Quick Start Page](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart#translate-text) super easily shows how you can translate text.

You'd start by making a project on the Google Developer Console. Then you would enable the Translate API and follow the instructions on the Quick Start Page to get your API Key.

Once you have your API key, you can use URLs to translate words.
For example, if you wanted to translate "hello world" from English into German, you'd follow this example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de
```

Of course where it says "YOUR_API_KEY" you would input the API Key that you made on the Google Developer Console.

Then, if you want to integrate this onto a website so a popup would show when you click a word, you can use jQuery to detect the word that you clicked. Then you would make an AJAX request using the format of the URL above (instead of "hello world" being in the url this time, it would be whatever word that you clicked).

The AJAX request would return a JSON object, which will contain the translated word that you are looking for. Then with more jQuery, you can display the word that was translated in a popup.

Comment: Thank for reply, I search and i catch word when click by jquery, and try translate is.